# Jquery autocomplete with modified return values

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Is there a way to check the received document if it has a value for one document field, split the value of that document field and return as many results as the split returns and show these as suggestions?

```
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data.response.docs, function (item) {
        var mark = "";
        if (item.attribute) {
            att = item.attribute.split(",");
        }

        return {
            // return as many suggestions as there is index in att
            // for each item in att
            // headsearch + att[i]

        };

    }));
```

If a document contains following values:

`tv | 42", hdmi, HD`

Suggestions will be

`tv 42"`

`tv hdmi`

`tv HD`

Comment: Is this being returned as a JSON file object node thing? As in, it sends back `{"tv":" 42\", hdmi, HD"}`

Comment: Or is it sending `tv | 42", hdmi, HD` back as a String?

Comment: It's returned as json

Comment: okay, so just use `$.getJSON("/url/", function(d){...})`

Comment: your right, i wasnt thinking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/k7DgA/1/).

You'll need to change a few things so that it works in practice. Here's what the changed code would look like.

the html:

```
<div id="my_text"></div>
<button id="someID">click me!</button>
```

the script:

```
//this is the .post or .get thing:
$("#someID").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON("/url/", function (d){
         var name = d.split("|")[0];
         var rest = d.split("|")[1].split(",");
         var lngh = rest.length; //so as to not be inefficient with the loop
         for (var i = 0; i < lngh; i++){
            $("#my_text").append(name + rest[i] + "<br>");
         }       
    })
})
```